# timeout sql server on a fast query

Tags: sql-server, timeout, sqlclient

I'm 100% sure that this question is a duplicate but I searched for a few hours and I didn't find anything.

My environment : windows server 2003, sql server 2005 , .net 2.0 (c#)

My problem :

When I run 5 request in the same time , one of my stored proc raises a time-out.

If , during the period the 5 request are waiting, I run in Management Studio, I try to call this stored proc with the same argument, I get my results in 0sec :)

I tried to see if I have too much connection opened but I can't see anything in activity monitor (I can see 14 item with "awaiting command").

So what is my problem ? I think it's a configuration missing , if it is, can you explain me how I will choose the value of this configuration.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using transactions anywhere?

Comment: Nope, no transaction, it's only a select

Comment: yes it does, one is a really big string, I'm just reading http://www.sqlpointers.com/2006/11/parameter-sniffing-stored-procedures.html , but what I don't understand is why my sp runs fine when I try in in MSSMS ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try altering the isolation level of the select statement in the SP using a table hint.

For instance:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM Table1 WITH (READUNCOMMITTED)
```

There are several other isolation levels but READ UNCOMMITTED is the lowest and will read from a table that is exclusively locked.  The downside is you can get dirty reads.

If the issue is with locking, this might help.